# C - extract integer between two comma from string

Tags: c, split

I have a char array containing `bicho,25,25-04-2000`. 
I want to extract `bicho` and put it in a variable and the same goes for `25` and `25-04-2000`.

I tried `strtok()` and `sscanf`, but no luck at all.

here is my method that i used:

```
fp = fopen(fn,"r");
while(!feof(fp)){
  fgets(data, 255,fp);
  puts(data);
  pch = strtok (data,",");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
  }
}
```

I want to store each value in separate variable not print it.

Comment: What did you try? Where's your "try"? your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822660/how-to-parse-a-string-separated-by-commas

Comment: please tell how did you try and failed

Comment: @rootkea here is my code,         

fp = fopen(fn,"r");
 while(!feof(fp)){
  fgets(data, 255,fp);
  puts(data);
  pch = strtok (data,",");
  while (pch != NULL)
    {
   printf ("%s\n",pch);
   pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
 }

Comment: @engineer yes i know this method but i want to store each one in separate variable so i can work with it later.

Comment: @ZeroOne Update it in the question.

Comment: `while(!feof(fp))` does not work as you think.

Comment: @rootkea done! can you please help me !

Comment: @Olaf how's that !!!

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.10.2. For details just search a bit here! (3 exclamation marks don't change facts)

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `feof` is not necessary. You can use `fgets` as the loop condition. Then it is just a matter of storing the strings in an array. You can then numerically convert your number with `strtol` or `atoi` (if needed). For example, you could do something like:

```
#define MAXL 10
#define MAXC 32

char array[MAXL][MAXC] = {{0}};
size_t index = 0;

if (!(fp = fopen (fn, "r"))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error: file open faied '%s'.\n", fn);
    return 1;
}

while (fgets (data, 255,fp)) 
{
    char *p = data;
    if ((p = strtok (data, ","))) {
        size_t plen = strlen (p);
        if (plen + 1 < MAXC)
            strncpy (array[index++], p, plen + 1);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: string exceeded MAXC\n");

        while (index < MAXL && (p = strtok (NULL, ",\n")) != NULL)
        {
            plen = strlen (p);
            if (plen + 1 < MAXC)
                strncpy (array[index++], p, plen + 1);
            else
                fprintf (stderr, "error: string exceeded MAXC\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Using a for Loop**

You can do the same thing with a `for` loop a bit more efficiently:

```
while (fgets (data, 255,fp) 
{
    char *p = data;
    for (p = strtok (data, ","); index < MAXL && p; p = strtok (NULL, ",\n"))
    {
        size_t plen = strlen (p);
        if (plen + 1 < MAXC)
            strncpy (array[index++], p, plen + 1);
        else
            fprintf (stderr, "error: string exceeded MAXC\n");    
    }
}
```

**note:** by confirming the length `plen` before you copy to your array, you can insure your strings are *nul-terminated*. Let me know if you have further questions.